# Restrict Google App Engine Endpoints API access

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I restrict Google App Engine Endpoints API access to only one email domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the `User` object to any of the endpoint API Methods that you want. On successful authentication, the User object will be populated and you can access various methods like getEmail(), getAuthDomain(), etc to perform your check.

Take a look at :

- [Adding User Parameters to Methods for Authentication](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth)
- [User Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User)